# How do I show that the arc swept by $(1+\frac{i}{n})^n$ has length 1?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm working on a tutorial for Euler's identity, and trying to show that the sum of the lengths of the arrows in this picture converges to 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$

[image]

The length of the bottom arrow is $\frac{1}{n}$, and each arrow gets longer by a factor of

$$\left|1 + \frac{i}{n}\right| = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

so, the total length is the geometric sum

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)^k}{n}
=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1 - \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)^n}{\left(1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)n}
$$

I've fiddled with this a lot and I can't seem to get it into a form where I can take the limit.

Comment: What is i, is it the imaginary unit ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: The limit expression you have falls to the squeeze thm. Note that $1+n^{-2} > 1$. Thus, the sum you have is lower bounded by $1$, and upper bounded by $\frac{n (1 + n^{-2})^{n/2}}{n} = (1 + n^{-2})^{n/2}.$ Since $(1 + x)^{1/x} \le e,$ we have $(1 + n^{-2})^{n/2} \le e^{1/2n} \to 1$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $z=\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n$ is the value at the tip of each arrow? I tried plotting that starting with $n=1$ and got nothing like that.

Comment: @CyeWaldman The value at the tip of each arrow is $\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^k$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ (for the arrow just above the horizontal axis) to $n$ (for the last arrow in the counterclockwise direction).  The goal is to compute the value of the last arrow, which is $\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^n$.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Sorry, the last sentence I wrote was wrong.  The goal is to compute the sum of the lengths of the arrows.  The complex multiplication $\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^k$ can be built up by noticing that $z\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)$ is a complex number whose magnitude is $\left|v\right|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ and whose argument is that of $z$ plus $\arctan\frac{1}{n}$.  The figure consists of a series of right triangles; the length of the long leg of one triangle is the length of the hypotenuse of the previous.  (That's the $\left|z\right]$ mentioned above.)  The short leg of the...

Comment: ...first triangle has length $\frac{1}{n}$.  In each subsequent triangle, the length of the short leg grows by a factor $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n\to \infty$ we have $ \frac{1}{ n^2}\to 0$

As you know as $x\to 0$ we have $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac{x}{2}$ thus

as $n\to \infty$ we have $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2n^2}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 - \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)^n}{\left(1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)^n}{n\left(1-1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-\left(1+n\frac{1}{2n^2}+\ldots\right)}{-\frac{1}{2n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{2n}}{-\frac{1}{2n}}=1$

Terms in parenthesis $(\ldots)$ go to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ because they are $\dfrac{const}{n^k}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: This polygonal path approaches the arc of the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to $e^i = (\cos 1,\sin 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your limit as
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-\exp\left(\frac{n}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)}{\left(1 - \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)\left(\exp\left(\frac{n}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)-1\right)
$$
Then Taylor expand the second factor in parentheses in powers of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought to chime in here with a slightly different point of view. For large $n$ we can take $z=\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^k$ to be a continuous function, say

$$z=\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^t$$

Now, the arc length in the complex plane is given by

$$s=\int |\dot z|~dt$$

First, let's simplify the algebra by letting $a=\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)$, then we can determine

$$
z=a^t\\
\dot z=\ln(a) ~a^t\\
|\dot z|=|\ln(a)|\cdot |a|^t,\quad |a|=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$

Now we can construct the integral as follows

$$
\begin{align}
s
&=\int_0^n |\dot z|~dt\\
&=|\ln(a)|~\int_0^n |a|^t~dt\\
&=\frac{|\ln(a)|}{\ln (|a|)}|a|^t\biggr|_0^n\\
&=\frac{|\ln(a)|}{\ln (|a|)}(|a|^n-1)\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, noting that

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots\\
(1+x)^n=1+nx+\cdots
$$

we can determine that for large $n$

$$
|\ln(a)|\approx \frac{1}{n}\\
\ln(|a|)\approx \frac{1}{2n^2}\\
|a^n|\approx 1+\frac{n}{2n^2}
$$

And finally.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s=\frac{2n^2}{n}(1+\frac{n}{2n^2}-1)=1$$